# Як влучніше перекласти слово "climb"?

Tags: переклад

У настільних рольових іграх є уміння, яке англійською позначається коротким "climb skill". У російськомовних перекладах воно визначене громіздким "СКЕЛЕЛАЗІННЯ", хоча не зовсім відповідає значенню, прив’язуючи вміння лише до скель. Climb — одне з тих влучних гарнюніх коротеньких англійських слів, які не мають аналогів в українській мові. Означає “підйом вгору”. Не має значення яким способом. Пішки, драбиною, мотузкою, на руках, на голові. “Лазіння”, “Видирання”? Перша думка точно буде не про стіну чи скелю.  “Сходження”?  На гору так. На стіну, дерево? Мате ще якісь варіанти?

Comment: Ви ж самі кажете - *підйом вгору*.

Comment: а одним словом?

Comment: @Yola В мене таке відчуття, що потрібно написати у вікі ukrainian.stackexchange.com, що українською, зазвичай, неможливо перекласти англійські слова одним словом, а ті переклади, котрі існують - це часто неусталені неологізми або також неусталений сленг.  Крім того, всі переклади українською в 99% - контекстуальні, в нас для одного англійського слова, зазвичай, є 20+ перекладів.

Comment: @improbable, посміхнули, дякую.

Comment: Але ж цікаве питання, чому в одному випадку англійське слово застосовується, наприклад, на три дії, а українське може бути на ті самі дії від 1 до трьох слів для кожної. І навпаки, на три дії в українській мові можна використати одне слово, в той час англійською декілька. Чому так складно? І де компроміс? Чи можливо спрощувати? Відкидати не потрібні слова чи навпаки пояснювати необхідність різниці? Якщо одна мова вказує на те, що є різниця в цих діях, то теоретично інша повинна засвоїти цю різницю та сприйняти це. Де та золота середина і як її добути?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko "Чому так складно? І де компроміс? Чи можливо спрощувати? [...] Де та золота середина і як її добути?"
Відповіді на всі ці запитання дають посібники з теорії перекладу.
Якщо коротко, то ідеальний переклад - саме те, що хотів сказати автор. Це може включати інформацію, емоцію, стиль, або все разом. Залежно від мети треба підбирати переклад. Майже завжди треба залежно від контексту і з оглядом на мету перекладу. Шукати переклад не слова, а лексичної одиниці, одиниці інформації. І змиритися, що для багатьох слів універсального перекладу не існує.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Словники

[**Climb**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/climb)

> - to go up, or to go towards the top of something:

*іти вгору, або йти до вершини чогось*

> The plane climbed quickly to a height of 30,000 feet.

*Літак швидко піднявся на висоту 30 000 футів.*

> As it leaves the village, the road climbs steeply up the mountain.

*Коли покидають село, дорога круто піднімається на гору.*

> The sun climbed higher in the sky.

*Сонце зійшло вище в небо.*

... і далі все в цьому дусі.

[**СХІД**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4)

> Дія за знач. схо́дити
>
> Дорога, по якій піднімаються вгору. Приклади
>
> ```
> Висока гора, і схід на неї крутий, змією кругом шпиля так і обвився. (Панас Мирний)
> ```
>
> Поява над обрієм (небесного світила). Приклади
>
> ```
> До сходу сонця, рано-рано! У Вифлеємі на майдані Зійшовся люд. (Т. Шевченко)
> Вона [агава] бачить море і скелі, перша стрічає схід сонця, остання ловить червоний захід. (М. Коцюбинський)
> В лісі поночіє, але темрява не густа, а прозора, як буває перед сходом місяця. (Леся Українка)
> Намалював [дружочок] картину життя на цьому спеченому острові, картину сходу сонця, коли воно вертикально підіймається на пекуче небо. (Ю. Яновський)
> ```
>
> Здатність тіста підніматися, підходити. Приклади
>
> ```
> Мука ясна, не пріла, на схід славна, тісто гарно бродить, і прісне славно міситься, біле, в'язке. (К. Гордієнко)
> ```
>
> Дія за знач. схо́дити 2. Приклади
>
> ```
> Нема дощу, – нема сходу. (Сл. Б. Грінченка)
> Виорав [Микула] пізно, кинув у ріллю все своє жито, але скільки туди не ходив, скільки не дивився, не діждався буйного сходу. (С. Скляренко)
> Як пахнуть землі, свіжі, соковиті, Пронизані стрільчастим сходом трав! (М. Бажан)
> ```
>
> рідко. Спуск, сходження вниз.

#### Я теж маю слово

> Climb — одне з тих влучних гарнюніх коротеньких англійських слів, які
>   не мають аналогів в українській мові.

Як мало ми знаємо про свою мову і в той же час вважаємо, що добре розуміємо іноземну.

#### “Сходження”? На гору так. На стіну, дерево? Мате ще якісь варіанти?

Схід, [підйом](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC), [лаз](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7). [Сходити](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8), [підніматися](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), [вилазити](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8), [дертися](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), [видиратися](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), [вилізати](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [здійматися](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F).